# Salesforce1 Today App customization

Tags: salesforce1-app, tasks, event

Is it possible to somehow customize standard "Today" app for Salesforce1 application?

What I mean exactly: I want it to look like "Home" in normal Salesforce. So I need for example list of today tasks and events.

I cannot find any documentation or answer about that anywhere, but I'm nearly 100% sure that it is somehow possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible (as of Winter '18).

There is an idea you can vote on: [Customize the Today App for Salesforce1 Mobile](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSZwQAO)

An alternative solution seems to be building your own version via the Lightning App Builder. [Reference from the Developer Forums](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DGgfAAG)

Comment: Building it using lightning app builder was my "emergency" solution. Too bad its not customizable, but thansk for the input.